# how to do a two parameter (two indepenent variable) fitting properly with scipy

Tags: python, numpy, parameters, scipy, minimum

I was trying to do a two parameter fitting with scipy curve_fit and minimize, however I could not do it properly.

For example, the following example always fails.

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np

def func(pars, x,y):
    a, b, c = pars
    return a*x+b*y+c*np.ones_like(x)

x = np.linspace(100,200,100)
y = np.linspace(500,810,100)
a, b, c = 1.5, -2.0, 0.5
z = func((a,b,c),x,y) + np.random.random(100) / 100


def resid(pars,x,y,z):
    return ((func(pars,x,y)-z)**2).sum()


p0 = [1.0,-2.5,0.8]
res = minimize(resid,p0,args=(x,y,z),method='CG')

print(res)
```

any ideas? also how this example should work with scipy curve_fit

Answer (score 1):

Here's a minimum example to your problem using `curve_fit` sintax. Without entering into too much detail, in order to ensure your coefficients are as close to your test values, generally you need some (or all) of the following conditions:

1. your initial guess is close to your actual values
2. your boundaries enclose your actual values and are as narrow as possible
3. there are limited "optimal" solutions

Since in your case number 3 is not possible (you can find other coefficients that match your values perfectly), you need to go with number 1 and 2. Code below:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize, curve_fit
import numpy as np

#note that curve_fit expects a function of the type f(x, a, b, c...), where x can be a vector

def func(x, *pars):
    a, b, c = pars
    return a*x[0]+b*x[1]+c*np.ones_like(x[0])

x = np.vstack((np.linspace(100,200,100), np.linspace(500,810,100)))
a, b, c = 1.5, -2.0, 0.5
z = func(x, a, b, c) + np.random.random(100) / 100

p0 = 0, 0, 0
bounds = ([0, -4., 0],[2, 0, 2])
popt, pocv = curve_fit(func, x, z, p0, bounds=bounds)
print(popt)
>>[ 1.49177259e+00 -1.99734466e+00  2.13002331e-11]
```

Comment: thank you for your help. I think the key point here you showed is the role of bounds. If we remove the bounds, the fitting becomes crazy again. Can you further explain why fitting of number 3 (c) is not possible? is it because it is a constant and has nothing to do with the variables?

Comment: No, that shouldn't be a problem. I think it is because of the function and the sample values. You can try plotting the results of the function vs. the fit with and without bounds. If you find reasonable matching with different parameters then the problem is that your system has different good solutions.